What's is the relationship between WebApplicationBuilder and WebApplication in ASP.NET Core web applications?
Why does ASP.NET Core define both WebApplicationBuilder and WebApplication?
It seems like WebApplicationBuilder is a factory, which can build multiple WebApplications. But why would a web application ever have more than a single WebApplication?
All configuration, like DI, configuration, and logging, belongs to the WebApplicationBuilder, while middleware belongs to the WebApplication?
Bonus: Does the WebApplication include a complete Kestrel web server for serving the application, commonly referred to at the host?
Example:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplication?view=aspnetcore-8.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplicationbuilder?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Not sure, what exactly your concern is. ASP.NET Core defines both WebApplicationBuilder and WebApplication to clearly separate the concerns of configuration/setup and execution/runtime. This separation helps in organizing the code better and makes the development process more intuitive. While it's theoretically possible for WebApplicationBuilder to create multiple instances of WebApplication, it's generally uncommon for a single web application to have more than one WebApplication instance.
